# Column matching in two files [Special case when any member is missing?]

Tags: awk

I have two text files which are a different size.  The first one  below example1.txt has only one column of numbers:

```
101
102
103
104
111
120
120
125
131
131
131
131
131
131
```

And the Second text file example2.txt has two columns:

```
101     3
102     3
103     3
104     4
104     4
111     5
120     1
120     1
125     2
126     2
127     2
128     2
129     2
130     2
130     2
130     2
131     10
131     10
131     10
131     10
131     10
131     10
132     10
```

The first column in the  example1.txt is a  subset of column one in example2.txt.  The second column numbers in example2.txt are the associated values with the first column.

What I want to do is to get the associated second column of example1.txt following the  example2.txt. I have tried but couldn't figure it out yet. Any suggestions or solutions in bash, awk would be appreciated

Therefore the result would be:

```
101     3
102     3
103     3
104     4
111     5
120     1
120     1
125     2
131     10
131     10
131     10
131     10
131     10
131     10
```

Using this awk it worked well for the above two texts file.

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]++; next} ($1 in a) && b[$1]++ < a[$1]' example1.txt example2.txt
```

**THE PROBLEM I'M FACING**

Now I'm working in a large file following the same awk commands. And from that result, the row numbers I'm getting are less than the example1.txt. I was not able to debug the problem. My guess is sometimes when any row is missing with the example1 column, they get skipped.

UPDATE SUGGESTION FROM  Ed Morton:

I'm writing here the suggestion from Ed Mortion , to check what output we are getting. Following the awk command,     `awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]++; next} ($1 in a){print $1, a[$1]}' b.txt  a.txt > c.txt`
 It's counting the repetitive common numbers in column 1 ( of b.txt  file) number, and the frequency is then posted as the column 2 of (a.txt) in the output file c.txt.

```
   a.txt

101
102
103
104
111
120
120
125
131
131
131
131
131
131

    b.txt:
    101 3
    102 3
    103 3
    104 4
    104 4
    111 5
    120 1
    120 1
    125 2
    126 2
    127 2
    128 2
    129 2
    130 2
    130 2
    130 2
    131 10
    131 10
    131 10
    131 10
    131 10
    131 10
    132 10




    c.txt:

    101 1
    102 1
    103 1
    104 2
    111 1
    120 2
    120 2
    125 1
    131 6
    131 6
    131 6
    131 6
    131 6
    131 6
```

If we dont use `a[$1]++`,in the above awk command we get in outout c.txt:

`awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]; next} ($1 in a) && b[$1]++ < a[$1]' example1.txt example2.txt`

```
 101
    102
    103
    104
    111
    120
    120
    125
    131
    131
    131
    131
    131
    131
```

Comment: `awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]++; next} ($1 in a){print a[$1]}' example2.txt example1.txt` would be the more obvious solution to your original problem. Try just doing that and let us know if you still have the problem you're asking about or not. If you are then get rid of all the `.`s in your sample input/output and make whatever other changes you need to to them to give us something we can test with.

Comment: Thanks, I think what you suggested might work. How do I print the 1st column of the  example1  as well?  Now it's printing only the second column matching the first file.

Comment: Change `print[$1]` to `print $1, a[$1]` or `$2=a[$1]; print`. You can also change `a[$1]++` to just `a[$1]`, the `++` is doing nothing useful, I shouldn't have added it.

Comment: @EdMorton, Would you like to write it as an answer? I can accept it :)

One thing is that I had to use a[$]++ and it worked just fine. Using only a[$] did not print the second column in the output file. Could you just tell me why?

Comment: I assume when you write `a[$]` you mean `a[$1]`. Using `a[$1]++` instead of `a[$1]=$2` simply cannot possibly work. If you clean up your sample input/output so there's just 1 set of it (you currently have 2 different sets, one of which is under "The problem I'm facing" but contains a bunch of "."s) that when tested against will provide a pass/fail result so we have something to test against then I can do so and if my attempt produces the expected output you provide from the sample input you provide then I'll post it as an answer.

Comment: @EdMorton Morton, There is no . in the txt files, I gave in the example question just to show that the file was huge. 

I have tested what you suggested and it works well.  `awk NR==FNR{a[$1]++; next} ($1 in a){print $1, a[$1]}` `example2.txt example1.txt`


I have just one comment, 
If the example2 file had three or more than two-column, I think we can print them out following the same awk command?  like for three columns: 
`awk NR==FNR{a[$1]++; next} ($1 in a){print $1, a[$1], a[$3]}` `example2.txt example1.txt`

Comment: Yes, I know why you put the `.`s there, I'm saying if you get rid of them and do whatever else you need to do to provide sample input we can run a script against and expected output that we can diff our tools output against for a success/fail result then we'll be able to help you better. Again, doing `a[$1]++` makes absolutely no sense to `get the associated second column of example1.txt following the example2.txt` as you said is your goal so I have no idea why you think it does what you want.

Comment: @EdMorton, I have updated the question with your suggestions. What it did was summing all the same row numbers in column 1 from example1.txt file  and we had that printed in column two in output file.

Comment: Im sorry, I have no idea what it is you're trying to do or why you're using the script you're using. Hopefully someone else will be able to help you.

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following.

```
awk '
FNR==NR{
  array[$1]=$2
  next
}
($1 in array){
  print $1,array[$1]
  found[$1]
}
END{
  print "Following are values present in example2 but not in example file"
  for(j in found){
     print j
  }
}
' file2 file1
```

***Suggestion to OP for OP's code:*** you are increasing value of array a with index of first field which is NOT needed, since value is present in its 2nd column itself

EDIT:

```
awk '
FNR==NR{
  array[$1]=$2
  next
}
($1 in array){
  print $1,array[$1]
  found[$1]
}
END{
  for(j in found){
     print j
  }
}
' file2 file1 | sort -n
```

Each time it starts filling the second column, it misses the first time always repetitively. like this:

**UPDATE for  @RavinderSingh13**

The example is from another big txt file that is mentioned.

```
31 65 
32
32 25 
32 25 
32 25 
32 25 
32 25 
32 25 
32 25 
32 25 
32 25 
33
33 65 
33 65 
~
```

Comment: I still have the same problem. Is there any way I can verify that if some of the rows from example1.txt are not available in the example.txt? That would be a good way to debug?

Comment: @zero_field, your post didn't show that. I have updated my answer now, please check it and lemme know then.

Comment: Thanks, I understand your command thanks.  can we fill 0 in the associated second column for the rows that are missing, and we also keep the column 1 in the ascending order as it was?

Comment: I forgot to write that, there are missing numbers indeed as it did print out at the end of the output file according to the awk command you suggested.

Comment: I wrote the comment in your answer section, so it is visible and others will not get confused, Please delete it once you get that.

Comment: @zero_field, it looks like total different question from what you asked initially :( please don't change your requirements, I didn't understand question BTW.